# Automatically update PostGIS layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

Is there a way to update a PostGIS layer in QGIS (every 5 minutes for example) without needing to right click on the layer and going through the Update SQL layer dialogue as shown below?

[image]

The end goal is to have a live spatial layer that can be updated elsewhere by other users and for those updates to be reflected in the QGIS project as people work in that without them having to manually update the layer themselves.

FYI I am using QGIS 3.4.1

Comment: This question is better addressed to DBMS specialists who will write a trigger or function, update, which will be automatically updated for your tables, for example, every 5 minutes, according to your request...

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want changes in the DB to be shown in QGIS, without having to do anything (not even pan the map a bit), or are you interacting with the map and you don't see DB updates until you refresh the SQL query?

Comment: @JGH I currently can't see updates in QGIS until I refresh the SQL query with the method described in the question

Comment: Just ZoomIn or ZoomOut should show the updates in the layer.

Comment: @iRfAn zooming in and out does not appear to update it for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the PostgreSQL notify commands. Read the following article https://oslandia.com/en/2017/10/07/refresh-your-maps-from-postgresql/

Comment: Thanks for this, I did not know this was possible. I haven't tested it yet but it appears to be what we are looking for.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just set the layer refresh in the properties of the layer under Rendering. This will just refresh your layer at a specific interval. This might have performance issue if your data is big

Comment: I tried this but it does not update as you would expect - it appears that it still needs to be manually updated.