# Update virtual field on demand (not permanently) (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, virtual-field

I quite often use virtual fields. Some of them are relatively complex aggregates. Since virtual fields updates on every input, by moving the map, open the attribute table and so on, it can cost a lot of CPU-Resources.

Is there a way to suppress the permanent update of a virtual field or just update it on demand? F.e. it would be fine, if virtual fields updates just by saving the layer or ending the edit mode.

Comment: If your data is stored in postgis, you could use a materialized view (postgresql.org/docs/12/rules-materializedviews.html) and only refresh it when needed.

Comment: I use GeoPackage and can not migrate to PostGIS

Comment: Script it and link it with a layer action.

Comment: A regular (non materialized) view would perhaps work and would be easy to test. Create the view, add it to QGIS, edit the data, pan/zoom the map and see what happens. I think you need to right-click "Update SQL Layer" on the layer to get the view to refresh within a QGIS project - see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302302/automatically-update-postgis-layer-in-qgis/302323

Comment: Is this a hypothetical question about "cpu resources" or is this about a real world problem? If it's the former one, a good answer will include details about when virtual fields are calculated. If it's the later one, an update to the question for the problem at hand would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the field normal (non-derivative). Runing this piece of code in QGIS as a Python script defines a recomputation function which activates before saving changes to the layer. You can implement your own logic there with any expressions for any fields.

You can also connect this function to an action button if you want to recompute on demand.

```
def recomputeField(vlayer):
    #recomputes field for chosen layer
    #example case: there are fields a, b and c is the derivative field

    #put your virtual field expression here
    virtualFieldExpr = 'a + b'
    expression = QgsExpression(virtualFieldExpr)

    context = QgsExpressionContext()
    context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(vlayer))

    for f in vlayer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f['c'] = expression.evaluate(context)
        vlayer.updateFeature(f)


#connect the function to vlayer.beforeCommitChanges signal
layerName = 'YOUR_LAYER_NAME'
vlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)[0]
vlayer.beforeCommitChanges.connect(lambda: recomputeField(vlayer))
```

EDIT:
Some advice on how to use this code. Paste it and run it in the editor (not directly in console cause it often causes syntax errors).

a, b, and c are your field names so replace them in code with the appropriate names for your fields.
Change the layerName to your desired layer name.
[image]

Comment: Sounds like the solution I was looking for, but I don't get it working (unfortunately I have no python experience): I tried to run it with python console: no error, no result and as Action: "unable to run command". I only changed the expression for testing from 'a + b' to '1 +2'. Using QGIS 3.14, Layer: GPKG. Could you please give more details for using this code?

Comment: I added some instructions in the main post.

Comment: Try running it as a script, not in console and remember to replace a, b and c in code with proper field names

Comment: Sorry to be the party stopper here, but including `iface.activeLayer()` is very fragile, 1. because it adds a dependency on the currently active layer, 2. because expressions can be evaluated in the background, and using layers in this context can affect stability.

Comment: I edited the code in accordance with Matthias's comment. The layer is chosen beforehand, instead of using iface.activeLayer()

Comment: Thanks. Please disregard the stability comment, this only applies if it's an expression function and not the implementation here. All good.

Comment: To what do I have to change the "beforeComitChanges.connect" to, if I want to start the script directly?

Comment: Delete the last line of code.
Add a new line at the end:
`recomputeField(vlayer)`.
This way it will only recompute at the moment you run the script.

Answer (score 4):

Virtual fields are great, but sometimes I think we get carried away with their usage within QGIS. (don't worry, im guilty too).

From a high level DB engineering perspective, ideally, calculated fields should occur either on database transactions when editing, or produce view tables, thus enabling the user to consume the view table instead. View tables would be suitable candidate replacements for virtual fields.

postGIS would be ideal, but you have mentioned your use of Geopackages. Geopackages are in essence a Sqlite database. Looks like some other users have attempted similar view table structures - see here [Create view table with QGIS and Geopackage](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328244/create-view-table-with-qgis-and-geopackage)
(BTW, that link doesn't actually have a solution, it just seems to show that others have tried and that there are some limitations).

Implementing code in QGIS to trigger events may be ok, but this will tie the virtual field creation to the QGIS application itself. This may or may not meet your publishing needs - for example, if its just yourself or other QGIS users, then that is probably ok - but if you are wanting this dynamic capability in - say a web mapping application, then the QGIS solution is not abstract and dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS supports this out of the box with "default values" and "apply on update"

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211154/9839